# Weird Ipsec behavior

Tags: networking, ipsec, strongswan

I am running into something interesting which I am not able to explain well.
I brought up a simple Ubuntu 20.04 box and attempting to protect all traffic via an IPSec tunnel.
I am not using VTI or xfrm interface and simply negotiating 0.0.0.0 as TS each end.
Without Ipsec tunnel, everything works fine.

Now when I initiate the tunnel, tunnels comes up fine.
Now when I run iperf TCP test, it works fine. Packets flow over tunnel, come back and hit the application and I get expected throughput.

When I run ping test, they work well as well.

The problem is WebTraffic.
When I do wget or try using a browser, I see traffic flowing well and coming back to my Ubuntu 20 node, however it never reaches the application.

So wget never sees the replies, however TCP connection as expected gets ESTAB and in wireshark I do see the replies both over Tunnel and post decryption.
But for inexplicable reason, its only when I try with web traffic that I notice that the traffic is not reaching the intended application.

Any clue.
My Ipsec config isn't anything interesting

```
vtewari@vtewari-ububtu:~$ sudo swanctl --list-sas
[sudo] password for vtewari: 
tenant-13543-1010: #9, ESTABLISHED, IKEv2, 43319062223514a3_i* 2927ffc3801b0fa2_r
  local  'vtewari-bom2@vtewari.com' @ 10.0.2.15[4500]
  remote 'vtewari-remote' @ vtewari-remote[4500]
  AES_CBC-128/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048
  established 2622s ago, reauth in 24647s
  tenant-13543-1010: #13, reqid 11, INSTALLED, TUNNEL-in-UDP, ESP:AES_CBC-256/HMAC_SHA1_96
    installed 2623s ago, rekeying in 68598s, expires in 69378s
    in  c6fce0ab,    600 bytes,     7 packets,   381s ago
    out c13ce846, 127082 bytes,    96 packets,   381s ago
    local  0.0.0.0/0
    remote 0.0.0.0/0

vtewari@vtewari-ububtu:~$ sudo swanctl --list-conns
tenant-13543-1010: IKEv2, reauthentication every 215460s, no rekeying
  local:  %any
  remote: vtewari-remote
  local pre-shared key authentication:
    id: vtewari-bom2@vtewari.com
  remote pre-shared key authentication:
  tenant-13543-1010: TUNNEL, rekeying every 71460s
    local:  0.0.0.0/0
    remote: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Ping/Iperf successful test over tunnel

```
vtewari@vtewari-ububtu:~$ iperf3 -c paris.testdebit.info -p 9237 -R
Connecting to host paris.testdebit.info, port 9237
Reverse mode, remote host paris.testdebit.info is sending
[  5] local 10.0.2.15 port 33296 connected to 89.84.1.194 port 9237
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  37.1 KBytes   304 Kbits/sec                  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   102 KBytes   830 Kbits/sec                  
^C[  5]   2.00-2.54   sec   131 KBytes  2.01 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-2.54   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-2.54   sec   270 KBytes   871 Kbits/sec                  receiver
iperf3: interrupt - the client has terminated
```

However though TCP gets connected, wget never sees the response

```
vtewari@vtewari-ububtu:~$ wget http://google.com --verbose -O index.html
--2022-06-05 15:10:00--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 142.250.77.46, 2404:6800:4009:81c::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|142.250.77.46|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2022-06-05 15:10:01--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 142.251.42.4, 2404:6800:4009:82f::2004
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|142.251.42.4|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                           [<=>                                                       ]       0  --.-KB/s
```

I see the same with browser as well.
If I disable tunnel, everything is fine. When I enable the tunnel, browser fails to reach servers.

Thank you for your insights into this.

Comment: firewall? MTU (as in: [PMTUD blackhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery#Problems))?